# Airflow Composer - unable to access config file stored in gcp storage, when using PythonOperator

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

i'm using Airflow Python operator, which calls an API to get data from external system, parses the data and puts in to MongoDB
(I guess i can use the SimpleHttpOperator as well).

In the method being called, i need to use the a config file (director_api.cfg), which has the credentials of the external system, and also the credentials for the Mongo instance.
The config file is stored in gcp storage bucket

Here is the dag code:

```
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow import models
from UpdateDirectorDataInMongo import main
# UpdateDirectorDataInMongo.py has the main method which is called in the PythonOperator task. This is stored in the same bucket as the dag file


with models.DAG(
        'Versa-directorinfo',
        # Continue to run DAG twice per day
        default_args=default_dag_args,
        schedule_interval=None,
        catchup=False,
        ) as dag:
    
        update_director_info = PythonOperator(
        task_id="update_director_info",
        python_callable=main
    )

    update_director_info


## UpdateDirectorDataInMongo.py - code where i try to access the director_api.cfg file

import configparser

self.api_username = parser.get("director-api", "user")
self.api_passwd = parser.get("director-api", "passwd")
self.mongoConnUri = parser.get('mongo', 'mongoConnUri') + "?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
 
# director-api.cfg (location is the same storage bucket as the dag file)

[director-api]
user=<user>
passwd=<passwd>

[mongo]
mongoConnUri=mongodb+srv://<user>:<passwd>@cluster0.w9yss.mongodb.net/<project>
```

Using the Python Operator, I'm unable to access the config file
error is shown below :

```
-04, 04:19:13 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1776} ERROR - Task failed with exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 174, in execute
    return_value = self.execute_callable()
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/operators/python.py", line 188, in execute_callable
    return self.python_callable(*self.op_args, **self.op_kwargs)
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/UpdateDirectorDataInMongo.py", line 86, in main
    customers = getCustomers()
  File "/home/airflow/gcs/dags/UpdateDirectorDataInMongo.py", line 72, in getCustomers
    mongoConnUri = parser.get('mongo', 'mongoConnUri') + "?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 781, in get
    d = self._unify_values(section, vars)
  File "/opt/python3.8/lib/python3.8/configparser.py", line 1149, in _unify_values
    raise NoSectionError(section) from None
configparser.NoSectionError: No section: 'mongo'
```

What needs to be done to fix/enable this ?
tia !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `director-api.cfg` was added in the root folder of `Cloud Composer` bucket, you can access to your file with the following way in the `UpdateDirectorDataInMongo.py` file :

```py
# Root path of Cloud Composer bucket
DAGS_FOLDER = os.getenv("DAGS_FOLDER")

parser.read([f'{DAGS_FOLDER}/director-api.cfg'])
```

You can also think about another and more secure solution :

- Add your secret variables in `Secret manager`
- In your `PythonOperator` use the `Google Cloud` `Python` client to access to secrets from `Secret manager` :

```py
from google.cloud import secretmanager

def _get_secret(project, secret_name, version='1'):
    client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()
    secret_path = client.secret_version_path(project, secret_name, version)
    secret = client.access_secret_version(secret_path)
    return secret.payload.data.decode('UTF-8')

your_secret_value = _get_secret(your_project, your_key)
```

Comment: thnx, that worked fine!

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, you need to have the `director-api.cfg` file in the same bucket/folder as the `UpdateDirectorDataInMongo.py` file.
Your DAG file is not important in this case, as the PythonOperator uses the `UpdateDirectorDataInMongo.py` as main.

Your parser should be like : `parser.read(['director-api.cfg'])`